# Is repeating keywords in subdomain useful?

Tags: domains, subdomain

Is repeating keywords in subdomain useful or not? For example my keyword is cars and my domains would look something like this:

- red.cars.com
- redcars.cars.com

Which would be is better?

Comment: None of them are good. Make domains and urls for your users, i.e `cars.com/red/`. But if you *MUST* separate the content to a sub domain then any relevant short word would work nicely. Keywords in domain are only indicators, you could rank a numeric url for keywords as long as other indicators have the keyword.

Comment: How domain names and sub-domain names are used in search can get rather complex- just know this- keyword matches against domain names is relatively rare and last in a list of matches Google makes, as well, it is the first place that Google looks for manipulation and will drop a site that appears to be gaming the system. Just don't do it. Make the site for people and not machines.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not. They are considered as Web Spam pretty much. In general using a sub-domain is a bad idea, except if you want to separate the content in some logical/semantic context, e.g.:

- you have a big corporate website and you want the website to be only for your corporate clients - sales, information on services, price plans and etc.; the blog is not related to your original conversion process so you separate it on sub-domain.